# Getting a Google Plus profile unsuspended 

Tags: google-plus, verification

Google+ has suspended my profile for using an invalid name.

I changed my name but my profile is still suspended. How do I get it unsuspended?

How do they check if the name entered is real or not? (Each language and people in different parts of world have different kind of names.)

Will Google ask me to put a "real" photo on my profile to avoid fake profiles?

Comment: I expect that the e-mail message you received to let you know you were in violation had a way to appeal.

Comment: As for how they check, your profile was probably reported by one or more people. I expect that if enough people report a profile they automatically suspend it. No, they're not going to force you to attach a photo to your profile.

Comment: I didn't recieve any email from google.

Comment: There is no one in my circles who can report. They all know the nick i use

Comment: Profiles are public. Anyone could have reported you.

Comment: Found this question via Google. @AlEverett -- I'm almost positive it's some sort of (badly-written) algorithm and very much doubt it's due to a community member reporting OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the "Contact Us" form from your profile page and ask for your profile to be reviewed.

Found this on the Google+ support forums:

> If your profile has been suspended, rather than start a new forum
>   thread to request an appeal, use our contact form linked from your
>   Google profile or visit
>   http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=suspended.
>   We don't currently have an option to check the status of your appeal,
>   but our support team reviews each profile. This may take some time,
>   and we appreciate your patience.